# Can I create more session objects in Flask?

Tags: python, cookies, web, flask

Basically what I want to do is to save some user-specific data, which I do not intend the user to be able to read.

This data should be stored for a week or so, but I can't use the `session` object, because I don't want to set `session.permanent = True` (I already use it to manage logins).

So basically I need a signed cookie, like session. Can I create an other instance of the session object somehow, or is there an easy way of making cookies signed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookies contents are up to you, it's more or less a key value store in your users' browsers with an expiration date.

Regarding the content, for your use case you can use any kind of symmetric encryption like Fernet for instance (available in the `cryptography` package, cf https://cryptography.io/en/latest/).

As far as I know, `itsdangerous` (from Flask author, cf http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/) enables you to sign the content of a cookie, but it doesn't "encrypt" it (the user will still be able to see the content, but not modify it). `itsdangerous` is a Flask dependency btw.

Comment: I went with fernet, but istdangerous also seems promising, so I guess I'll try it for some other purposes later. thanks :)